# Is it possible to deploy an already working ERP on Hyperledger fabric?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer, erp, hyperledger-chaincode

Is it possible to deploy my already working ERP (with slight modifications if needed) on Hyperledger fabric, or do i need to develop a new ERP for hyperledger fabric?

If someone could guide me of the pathway, it will be very much appreciated.

Note: It is a private application and needs to remain private and with very limited access.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can develop a sample POC to get/set data from already existing/ running ERP application. You can go through the link https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ to get a good picture of how can you design your application.

Comment: detail? you just add hyperledger fabric main page.

Comment: https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/private-data/private-data.html